# Background image not showing up on django website

Tags: python, css, django, heroku

I'm having a problem trying to get my website's background to show up. I created my website using html, css and django/python (for backend). I'm hosting my website with the helps of Heroku. The funny thing is, when I put in the heroku domain name of my website (http://desolate-gorge-2387.herokuapp.com/home/), the background shows up perfectly like so -

[image]

Now, when I type in my website's actual domain name (which is linked to the heroku domain name), I get this -

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening? I looked into the CSS file I'm using and I have clearly specified the file location of the background image. Here's my code -

```
html,
body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: url("../background-2.jpg") center no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
```

What seems to be going on here? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clear your browser cache and reload your website http://www.raghavkumar.work/home/ , i have checked it on Firefox and Chrome, and your background image is working well.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @afelixj One must have at least 50 reputation score to post a comment here, while i have earned only 21 so far.